# Memory ordering, instruction reordering and lack of happens-before relationship

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

**Relaxed ordering**

Atomic operations tagged with std::memory_order_relaxed are not synchronization operations; only the modification order of each individual atomic object is shared between threads. Different objects have no ordering between themselves relative to other threads; operations can be seen out of order.

**Example – Relaxed ordering**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
std::atomic<int> x{ 0 };
std::atomic<bool> x_is_set{ false };
std::atomic<int> counter{ 0 };
void f1()
{
    x.store(5, std::memory_order_relaxed);              // A
    x_is_set.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);    // B
}
void f2()
{
    while (!x_is_set.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));  // C

    if (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 5)         // D
        ++counter;                                      // E
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t1{ f1 };
    std::thread t2{ f2 };
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    assert(counter.load() == 1);                        // F
}
```

There are no ordering constraints between thread **t1** and thread **t2**. Therefore, the store done in **B** can be seen by **t2** before the store done by **A**; the assert **F** in main() will fire in that case.

The obvious solution to this issue is to make the store in **B** have `std::memory_order_release` and the load in **C** have `std::memory_order_acquire` for synchronization purposes. The assert in **F** would seemingly never fire.

**Question**

However, since there is no *happens-before* relationship between **A** and **B** (am I wrong?), can't the compiler/optimizer/CPU reorganize the instructions in function `f1()` such that **B** is *sequenced-before* **A**? This would cause **C** in function `f2()` to evaluate to `true`, but **D** would be `false`; the assert could fire.

Is there anything preventing that issue from arising?

Comment: A and B are in the same thread, and A is sequenced before B, so A happens before B.

Comment: A happens before B, but from another thread the side effect of B may be visible before the side effect of A.

Comment: I thought that even if A was sequenced-before B, if A didn't carry a dependency into B, there was no happens-before relationship. So just the fact that they're sequenced before means that there is a happens-before relationship?

Comment: @bku_drytt How would any program work then? How would you make any side effect visible?

Comment: I have the same confusion.  Other thread can observe the side effects in _f1()_ in any order due to many reasons. Is compiler/cpu reordering statements A and B one of the reasons? Since the stores in _f1()_ are for different atomic variables with _std::memory_order_relaxed_ ? If sequenced before relationship forces compiler to emit instructions in that order, then how does compiler get the freedom to optimize (like code reordering, elimination etc..)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since there is no happens-before relationship between A and B

Wrong. [intro.multithread]/p14:

> An evaluation A *happens before* an evaluation B if:
>
> - A is sequenced before B, or
> - A inter-thread happens before B.